# How do I render a filled and stroked path using OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, shaders, rendering, geometry, beziers

I want to render a 2-dimensional geometric path consisting of [Bézier curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) and straight lines. Paths can be [concave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_polygon).

What is the most efficient way to draw this using modern OpenGL? Can I do this with a vertex shader? How should I store the path segments?

Comment: The most straightforward thing to do is to tesselate the path to triangles on the CPU - which isn't trivial, but I assume there are libraries and such to do it - and then render the triangles normally with OpenGL.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is probably to use the NV_path_rendering extension: https://developer.nvidia.com/nv-path-rendering

If that won't work for you, you're going to essentially have to implement at least part of the functionality. The good news is that NV_path_rendering shows that it's possible; the bad news is that it's probably going to be a lot of effort, depending on your requirements.